# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <tab-bar-item> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components,

Tags: vue.js, components, slot

[App.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA3Fw.png)

[TabBaritem.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xunQd.png)

[the res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Laeq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub string `item` should be capitalized to `Item` :

```
name:'TabBarItem'
```

and in App.vue :

```
import TabBarItem from  ...

...

components:{
 TabBarItem,TabBar
}
```

because `tab-bar-item` expects a component named `TabBarItem`, it converts `PascalCase` to `kebab-case`